# How is i2c clock frequency value passed from BIOS to driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi

My `i2c clock-frequency` values is coming from BIOS.

I have extracted the `DSDT` and the `i2c clock-frequency` field is as follows:

```
         Device (I2C1)
        {
            Name (_ADR, 0x00160001)  // _ADR: Address
            Name (_DDN, "Intel(R) I2C Controller #1")  // _DDN: DOS Device Name
            Name (_UID, 0x02)  // _UID: Unique ID
            Name (LINK, "\\_SB.PCI0.I2C1")
            Name (RBUF, ResourceTemplate ()
            {
            })
            Name (_DSD, Package (0x02)
            {
                Buffer (0x10)
                {
                    /* 0000 */   0x14, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDA, 0xBA, 0x6E, 0x8C, 0x4D,
                    /* 0008 */   0x8A, 0x91, 0xBC, 0x9B, 0xBF, 0x4A, 0xA3, 0x01
                }, 

                Package (0x01)
                {
                    Package (0x02)
                    {
                        "clock-frequency", 
                        IC1S
                    }
                }
            })
```

But there is no mention of i2c clock frequency values for different modes like 400k, 1M etc. Where are these values defined? How is it being passed from BIOS to driver?

Comment: Modes are defined solely by **slave** devices connected to the host. That's why the above _DSD doesn't feel right. Otherwise the I2C clock is defined as slowest device connected. See some details here http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-i2c/msg24857.html

Comment: I have a strong feeling that these `i2c-clock-frequency` values have been defined in the BIOS source code. Because since we have the options in `BIOS` to select either `Standard Mode (100k)`, `Fast Mode (400k)`, `Fast Plus (1M)` & `High Speed (3.4M)`, these values should be matched somewhere in the BIOS source code. The kernel API `device_property_read_u32(&pdev->dev, "clock-frequency",
                                         &dev->clk_freq);` matches the `"clock-frequency"` `propname` field in `ACPI` & fetches the `i2c-clock-frequency` value from the `ACPI` object.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about **existing** BIOS in the wild?!

Comment: Btw, this one, i.e. `clock-frequency` property, is widely used in Device Tree. For ACPI there is no need to define that at all, since I already explained. In ACPI `I2cSerialBus()` defines speed of the certain slave device.

Comment: Yes, the **existing** BIOS in the market !  I got to know that these values have been currently `defined` in BIOS source code. As far as `DT` implementation is concerned, it makes sense. Don't know why did they `hard-code` in the **existing** BIOS though? Can't get a hand into it!

Comment: Can you elaborate what the device (platform, board, etc.) it is? Better some link to it. And can you share ACPI tables from it (use acpidump utility to collect a file which you may share)?

Comment: Well, I have got the answer to my question; but just to kill the curiosity - Its a `BXT` based platform. An `ACPIdump` file would reveal much more info than needed, that I am not supposed to right now. Sorry for that !

Comment: So, it means there is no such BIOS in the wild, right? Otherwise anyone can get a dump. If the BIOS is under development yet, the above should be fixed, otherwise it's clearly abuse of ACPI.

Comment: The one that I am using is surely not in the wild yet! But I don't know if there are any, already! Well, let me check how can I go around and get this thing fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These `i2c-clock-frequency` values have been defined in the `BIOS source code` (apparently). Because since we have the options in `BIOS` to select either `Standard Mode (100k), Fast Mode (400k), Fast Plus (1M) & High Speed (3.4M)`, these values should be matched somewhere in the BIOS source code. The kernel API

```
`device_property_read_u32(&pdev->dev, "clock-frequency", &dev->clk_freq);`
```

matches the `"clock-frequency" propname` field in `ACPI` & fetches the `i2c-clock-frequency` value from the `ACPI object`.